# while loop getting stuck - Openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, synchronization, openmp

I was trying to implement some piece of parallel code and tried to synchronize the threads using an array of flags as shown below

```
// flags array set to zero initially

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads (n_threads) schedule(static, 1)
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            while(!flag[j]);
            y[i] -= L[i][j]*y[j];
        }
        y[i] /= L[i][i];
        flag[i] = 1;
    }
```

However, the code always gets stuck after a few iterations when I try to compile it using `gcc -O3 -fopenmp <file_name>`. I have tried different number of threads like 2, 4, 8 all of them leads to the loop getting stuck. On putting print statements inside critical sections, I figured out that even though the value of flag[i] gets updated to 1, the while loop is still stuck or maybe there is some other problem with the code, I am not aware of.

I also figured out that if I try to do something inside the while block like `printf("Hello\n")` the problem goes away. I think there is some problem with the memory consistency across threads but I do not know how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The single threaded code I am trying to parallelise is

```
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < i; j++){
            y[i]-=L[i][j]*y[j];
        }
        y[i]/=L[i][i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have data race in your code, which is easy to fix, but the bigger problem is that you also have loop carried dependency. The result of your code does depend on the order of execution. Try reversing the `i` loop without OpenMP, you will get different result, so your code cannot be parallelized efficiently.

One possibility is to parallelize the `j` loop, but the workload is very small inside this loop, so the OpenMP overheads will be significantly bigger than the speed gain by parallelization.

EDIT: In the case of your updated code I suggest to forget parallelization (because of loop carried dependency) and make sure that inner loop is properly vectorized, so I suggest the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
    double sum_yi=y[i];
    #pragma GCC ivdep
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sum_yi -= L[i][j]*y[j];
    }

    y[i] = sum_yi/L[i][i];
}
```

`#pragma GCC ivdep` tells the compiler that there is no loop carried dependency in the loop, so it can vectorize it safely. Do not forget to inform compiler the about the vectorization capabilities of your processor (e.g. use `-mavx2` flag if your processor is AVX2 capable).

Comment: Thanks for the response. From what I have thought, the execution of the line y[i] -= L[i][j] * y[j] is the one carrying loop dependence and to remove the dependence, I have put the while loop before it, which stalls the execution of the statement until the correct value is put in y[j]. Wouldn't it resolve the issue then?

Comment: If you use or do not use the while loop, you get different result in a single threaded code. My suggestion is the following: update your post and show us the single threaded code you wish to parallelize and we tell you how to do it (if possible).